# Moq.MockException: The following setups on mock were not matched

Tags: c#, moq

In below code i am using `Moq` to write a sample test. I have created a Mock Object and I am using `SetupProperty` to setup fake value to be returned for the property. But i get above error at line `_sharedService.VerifyAll()`.

I know i am missing something trivial, but not exactly sure what. Could anyone please help?

```
[TestFixture]
public class ObjectFactoryTests : TestFixtureBase
{
    private Mock<ISharedService> _sharedService;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _sharedService = new Mock<ISharedService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    }

    protected override void VerifyAll()
    {
        _sharedService.VerifyAll();
    }

    private IObjectFactory GetObjectFactory()
    {
        return new ObjectFactory(sharedService.Object);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ObjectFactory_GenerateObject_Request_Success()
    {
        MyObject1 request = something;
        var requestData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        requestData.TryAdd(Cache.Client, Constants.CLIENT);
        _sharedService.SetupProperty(m => m.RequestData, requestData);
        var factory = GetObjectFactory();
        var actual = factory.GenerateObject(request);
        Assert.That(actual.Client, Is.EqualTo(requestData[Cache.Client].ToString()), Constants.CLIENT);

        VerifyAll();
    }
}

public class ObjectFactory : IObjectFactory
{
    ISharedService SharedService = something;

    public MyObject GenerateObject(MyObject1 request)
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(request);
        obj.Client = SharedService.RequestData[Cache.Client].ToString();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code does not look complete. 1. There is no constructor for the class ObjectFactory() which is called in GetObjectFactory(). 2. The line return new ObjectFactory(sharedService.Object), the sharedService does not have an underscore. Please post the complete code, and then we can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you try to setup property expectations.

Try following instead of `_sharedService.SetupProperty(m => m.RequestData, requestData);`:

```cs
_sharedService.Setup(foo => foo.RequestData).Returns(requestData);
```

You can read more information in [Moq documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#properties)

Answer (score 1):

For a get-set peoperty, `SetupProperty` will create two setups: one for the getter, and one for the setter. Since you're only reading the property, that leaves the property for the setter unmatched, therefore the error.

To avoid this, use `mock.SetupGet(m => m.Property).Returns(() => value)` to only create a setup for the getter.

Btw.: `SetupProperty` actually has a different purpose than what you might think: It shouldn't be used to set up an expectation; instead, it is used to "stub" a property such that it retains the value it's been set to last. The fact that `Verify[All]` even includes such stubbed properties in its checks is probably an error (which has already been fixed in `SetupAllProperties`).